# Unable to Implement angular-schema-form-signature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, signature, angular-schema-form

I'm unsure as to why an input field shows on the form when implementing this code.(ref: https://github.com/JamesGuthrie/angular-schema-form-signature)

**This is my Schema:**

{ "type": "object", "properties": { "signature": { "type": "string" } } }

**This is my Form:**

```
[
"name",
{
    "type": "tabs",
    "tabs": [
        {
            "title": "Tab1",
            "tabType": "top",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "Signature",
                    "key": "signature",
                    "type": "signature",
                    "width": 500,
                    "height": 100,
                    "resetButtonText": "Clear signature"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: I think the [tag:angular] tag is incorrect, it should be [tag:angularjs]

Comment: Add a link to a plunker to demonstrate what you have tried, without seeing the app script it is hard to know if you included or bound the library correctly or if something else has gone wrong.